# When an SSH authorized key is restricted to command how can the command read the parameters in the call?

Tags: ssh, command, openssh

Say an authorized key is restricted to the command to test parameters, eg `command="bin/testparameters"` and the ssh call is:

`ssh user@host 'some parameters which may include other commands'`

How can `bin/testparameters` read the value `'some parameters which may include other commands'`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The additional parameters passed to `ssh` appear in the environment variable `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND`:

```
$ tail -1 .ssh/authorized_keys
command="printf '%s\n' \"$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND\"" ssh-rsa AAAA....kz6C5 user@example.com
$ ssh user@example.com foo bar farkle
foo bar farkle
```